# Can I simulate the Intel Bay Trail processor cstate crash?

Tags: grub2, power-management, cpu

I've got a growing number of devices running Bay Trail processors and half of them are randomly shutting themselves off.  Thanks to other answers on this site, I'm reasonably certain it's fixed by setting max_cstate=1 in GRUB, although I'm not completely convinced of this since not every machine is shutting off and one of them appeared to have shut off even with the max_state=1 setting set.

I've been trying to use some of the [power maintenance utilities](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnderstandingSuspend) that are available for ubuntu, but I'm not sure exactly which one is the same as changing the processor cstate.

Is there a command that I can run to manually change the cstate of the processor to simulate what may be happening in the field?

Answer (score 2):

The [firmware test suite](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FirmwareTestSuite/Reference) contains a cstates test that tries to exercise C-states, it may be something to try:

```
sudo apt-get install fwts
fwts cstates -
```