# Linux 20.04 MCE Kernel Errors

Tags: 20.04, kernel

Built a new PC: 10700k, z490 MSI board, 32gb Ram etc. Running Ubuntu 20.04 and getting an MCE (Machine Check Error):  kernel: [    0.185888] mce: CPU0: Thermal monitoring enabled (TM1).

The PC is just running the Game boost from the MSI Bios, and not manually overclocked. Using a Corsair H115 2*140mm cooler, with temperatures on idle being at most 32 degrees per core.

Apart from getting these MCE errors, sometimes the PC completely freezes when left on idle. A force restart is the only option. What could this be?

Comment: Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: I have ran the memtest for hours as suggested, but everything is fine with the ram. What else could it be?

Comment: What processor? Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT model # of your motherboard. MSI Z490-what? Show me `free -h` and `sudo lshw -C memory` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. If you turn off "Game Boost" in the BIOS, any difference? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema sudo dmidecode -s bios-version : 1.00. MSI-z490 Gaming Edge Wifi

Comment: Free -h: Mem:           31Gi       2.5Gi        26Gi       419Mi       2.1Gi        27Gi

Comment: *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 1.00
       date: 03/24/2020
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 32MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi

Comment: *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 39
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 32GiB

Comment: vm.swappiness = 60

Comment: @heynnema Both Game boost and  XMP were turned off but the problem persists. The memory was also tested and I don't think that this is a memory swap problem as I have 32gb of ram.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks i will!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**memtest**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**BIOS**

MSI-Z490 Gaming Edge Wifi

You have BIOS version 1.00.

There's a newer BIOS available that might help solve your problem, version 1.30, dated 10/14/2020, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/MPG-Z490-GAMING-EDGE-WIFI).

Note: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your motherboard model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**/swapfile**

Even though you have a lot of memory, a swap partition or /swapfile is still recommended. Let's create a fresh /swapfile...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 32G RAM and 4G swap
```

Confirm this /swapfile line at the end of /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines...

To edit, use `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**vm.swappiness**

Since you have 32G RAM, to minimize swapping, let's change this value...

Set vm.swappiness=10 (based on 32G RAM and 4G SWAP), this way...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/sysctl.conf` # edit this file

Search for an existing `vm.swappiness=` entry...

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> vm.swappiness

- If found, **edit** it to say `vm.swappiness=10`
- If not found, **add** `vm.swappiness=10` at the end of the file

Save your edits and quit gedit

`sudo sysctl -p`

**Update #1:**

Set `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` in /etc/default/grub, and then `sudo update-grub` and `reboot` solved the problem.

Comment: I will update the BIOS. By any chance, does this motherboard have 2 UEFI/BIOS or a single chip? Just in case the Bios gets corrupted

Comment: @MatthewVella I don't know. Some manufacturer's build in some redundancy to safeguard the process.

Comment: @MatthewVella Status please...

Comment: I have updated the BIOS to the latest version. I will update this week if the problem is solved or persists. Thanks

Comment: I have also updated the swappiness value to 10, worked great!

Comment: @MatthewVella Good! Did you make the /swapfile?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the guide! If I have no issues for the next 3 days, I will mark it as the correct solution, as I usually have at least an issue every 3 days.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem still persists. MCE check errors and the pc froze again, turning off all devices including USB ports, wifi, Bluetooth chips etc.

Comment: @MatthewVella If I have to wager, I'd say bad CPU. Outside chance it could be a power supply, so if you have one, give it a try.

Comment: @MatthewVella Status please...

Comment: The PC is much more stable, hence I marked your answer as Correct. I do believe though there are Motherboard issues, as the PSU is working well and the CPU is ploughing trough benchmarks, but as soon as the PC is idle, it locks and shutdowns all the hardware. This is happening less frequently after the BIOS update.

Comment: @MatthewVella You may have a problem with a cstate parameter that needs tweeking. Search for `cstate` or `c-state` here on AU. Look for descriptions of a GRUB mod that looks similar to `intel_idle.max_cstate=1`. Example: https://askubuntu.com/questions/749349/how-to-set-intel-idle-max-cstate-1 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/896149/can-i-simulate-the-intel-bay-trail-processor-cstate-crash/896162#896162

Comment: Updating the C-State to 1, completely solved the issue! Thanks!